# Reading data back from an editable datagrid in flex

Tags: datagrid, flex3

I am having an editable datagrid which is populated using an XML object which in turn is populated via a HTTPService. 
The editable datagrid columns all have an itemrenderer with rendereriseditor property marked true. I need to send the edited data back to the server via an http service.

Is there a way that the changes made my the user are reflected back in the XML object?
or Is there a i can read the datagrid in its edited state row by row and store the data in my own objects?
or Any other tip when working in a scenario like this is also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If the itemRenderer data is directly bound to a reference to the datagrid's dataProvider, then editing the value directly edits the value in the dataProvider, which you can simply send back to the server.

Comment: Currently the XML object is binded to the datagrid's dataProvider. The itemremderers are independent flex components defined in seperate xml files. How do i create such a binding between the item renderer's data and the dataProvider?